# Getting Sum of MasterTable's amount which joins to DetailTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sum

I have two tables:
**1. Master**

```
| ID  |  Name  | Amount |
|-----|--------|--------|
| 1   |   a    | 5000   |
| 2   |   b    | 10000  |
| 3   |   c    | 5000   |
| 4   |   d    | 8000   |
```

**2. Detail**

```
| ID  |MasterID|  PID  |  Qty |
|-----|--------|-------|------|
| 1   |   1    |   1   |  10  |
| 2   |   1    |   2   |  20  |
| 3   |   2    |   2   |  60  |
| 4   |   2    |   3   |  10  |
| 5   |   3    |   4   |  100 |
| 6   |   4    |   1   |  20  |
| 7   |   4    |   3   |  40  |
```

I want to select `sum(Amount)` from *Master* which *joins* to *Deatil* where `Detail.PID in (1,2,3)`

So I execute the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Master M INNER JOIN Detail D ON M.ID = D.MasterID WHERE D.PID IN (1,2,3)
```

Result should be ***20000***. But I am getting *40000*
See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e71b2/1). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting exactly double the amount because the detail table has two occurences for each of the PIDs in the WHERE clause.

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e71b2/3/0)

Use

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) 
FROM Master M 
WHERE M.ID IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT MasterID
  FROM DETAIL
  WHERE PID IN (1,2,3) )
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the requirement of joining the master table with details when you have all your columns are in Master table.

Also, isnt there any FK relationhsip defined on these tables. Looking at your data it seems to me that there should be FK on detail table for MasterId. If that is the case then you do not need join the table at all.

Also, in case you want to make sure that you have records in details table for the records for which you need sum and there is no FK relationship. Then you could give a try for exists instead of join.

Comment: See the question again. I want the sum of amount master's table where pid of detail's table in (1,2,3) (pid is only in detail).

Comment: Then use the exists.                                                              SELECT SUM(Amount)  
FROM Master M  
WHERE exists  ( 
  SELECT 1 
  FROM DETAIL D
  WHERE PID IN (1,2,3) and d.MasterId = M.id)